# How can you get the default error string used when an optional-nil error is thrown?

Tags: swift, error-handling

We're implementing our own version of the `.required()` method on optionals where instead of simply force-unwrapping throwing an error, you get the file, function and line number of where the offense took place as well as a dev-supplied message of what went wrong.

The message itself is optional, so if the user doesn't specify it, we want ours to share the same message as Swift's default exception for force-unwrapping a nil optional. Their default text is this...

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

When not showing our custom message, we of course want ours to show the same text for log analysis.  While we can simply hard-code the above string, I was wondering if there's a way to extract it from the built-in error.  Something like this...

```
let ourMsg = UnexpectedNilError.localizedDescription
```

However, not sure what goes in place of `UnexpectedNilError` above, or if this is even possible.  Not that big a deal.  Just wondering if there are standard errors we can tap into here.

Comment: That aside, the actual error message is on [this line](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/da61cc8cdf7aa2bfb3ab03200c52c4d371dc6751/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift#L314). Doesn't seem like you can get it.

Comment: Um, yes, I know that.  That is the ***default*** message if the dev doesn't specify something specifically (it's our implementation of 'required'.  Look it up.) and I want my default to match Swift's. Either way, as you said, it can't be reached. If you can put that in an answer, I'll accept it to close this out.

Comment: @sweeper, I've updated the question to avoid misconceptions about what we're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick search on Swift's [repo](https://github.com/apple/swift), the error message is found in the file [Optional.swift line 314](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/da61cc8cdf7aa2bfb3ab03200c52c4d371dc6751/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift#L314):

```
_preconditionFailure(
  "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value",
  file: StaticString(_start: _filenameStart,
                     utf8CodeUnitCount: _filenameLength,
                     isASCII: _filenameIsASCII),
  line: UInt(_line))
```

It seems to be quite hardcoded as well, being passed directly as a parameter to `_preconditionFailure`, so it doesn't seem like you can get it as a string value in your code.

Comment: Damn! :/  (At least it looks like we can assume that ain't changing anytime soon so we can hard-code ours too.)

Comment: BTW, how do you 'search the Swift repo'.  I've always wanted to dig around in there.  Do you simply clone it to your machine, or can you do that directly on GitHub? (We use BitBucket (free private repos) but I'm assuming they're pretty similar.)

Comment: Found this... 'https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-code-for-exact-matches' but pressing 'F' doesn't bring up the search.

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe Go to a repo, then go to the search bar on the top left, type something in, and then in the suggestions box, you'll see "In this repository" and "All Github". Tap on the first one.

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks!  They must've updated the site since that help topic was written. (I thought that box was just for searching for repo names.  Thanks for the tip!)